# Why Android app dont reload into emulator Intellij IDEA after bugfix?

Tags: android, macos, intellij-idea, emulation

I wrote my first simple app for Android in Intellij Idea, load it into emulator, then I made some changes in layout and tried to load fixed app into emulator again, but I've got outdated app, not new fixed one. What I shoud do to run new app in the emulator?

Intellij IDEA 11.1.2 CE
Android 2.3.3
Android SDK tools r20
Mac OS X 10.7.4

--
Thanx in advance

Comment: Try IDEA 11.1.3 from http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+11.1+EAP. If it still doesn't work, provide a sample project and the steps to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it was a bug in IDEA 11.1.2 caused by the incompatibility with the new Android Platform tools released after that IDEA version. IDEA 11.1.3+ versions should work fine.